# disable or hide ASP listitem using jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui, c#-3.0

i have a asp:radio button with two list items

```
asp:RadioButtonList id=Myradio"
asp:listitem1 value="li1"
asp:listitem2 value="li2"
```

it is rendered as td for each listitem in horizontal orientation.

What i want to achieve is dynamically on some condition i have to show or hide the list item with value "li2".

i did some thing like this:

```
$('[value=li2]').hide();
```

this works but it is only hiding the radio button but not the label generated for that list item.
Generated markup:
table id=Myradio
tbody
tr  TD  input type="radio" checked="checked" value="li1" name="ctl03$Myradio id="ctl03_Myradio_0"
label for="ctl03_Myradio_0"  li1 
label
/td
TD  input type="radio" checked="checked" value="li2" name="ctl03$Myradio id="ctl03_Myradio_0"
label for="ctl03_Myradio_0"  li2 
label
/td

How i can fix that in jquery.

I am sorry i am not good at showing it in proper way.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with asp, could you post the html markup generated for the list items?

Comment: Need to see HTML. Can you wrap each radio button and its label into a div using asp? If so, you'd need to select parent div of your selected radio button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$('[value=li2]').parent().hide();

Comment: this works but if i make the RepeatLayout to Flow whole radiobuttonlist is hidden. I want some thing for both the layouts.

Comment: $('[value=li2]').hide(); $('[value=li2]').next().hide();   This will work with both default and RepeatLayout="Flow"

Answer (score 0):

If your html is like this

```
 <label for="li1">Uno</label>
 <input type='radio' id='li1' value='li1'>
 <label for="li2">Dos</label>
 <input type='radio' id='li2' value='li2'>
```

You can do this:

```
   $('[value=li2]').hide();
   $('[value=li2]').prev('label').hide();
```

If you can wrap each label and radio button in a div like this:

```
 <div>
 <label for="li1">Uno</label>
 <input type='radio' id='li1' value='li1'>
 </div>
 <div>
 <label for="li2">Dos</label>
 <input type='radio' id='li2' value='li2'>
 </div>
```

Then you can just do this:

```
  $('[value=li2]').parent().hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use accordion menu for that i think.

[Accordion menu](http://chandreshmaheshwari.wordpress.com/2011/05/27/accordian-menu/)

I think it would be helpful to you.

Thanks.